# Given Newton's 3rd Law, how is a sea-pumped hydro jetpack possible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

EDIT: I dont think it's an obvious duplicate. That Q just asks how a water jet pack works. My Q asks how 2 forces in 2 opposite directions producing 2 opposite-equal reactions can somehow produce a net thrust.

These are some hydro jet packs. There are plenty of youtube videos demonstrating them.

[image]

[image]

But note the water is pumped out of the sea and runs up a tube to the device. In other words, the mass flow of water has to take a **u-turn** at the top of the device.

So according to Newton's 3rd Law, there should be an opposite reaction for both directions: one for the initial pumping in an upwards direction, causing a downwards reaction...and one for the later expelling in a downwards direction, causing an upwards reaction. The mass flow of water has to be the same in both cases, so the two reactions should cancel each other out and result in no net thrust.

What am I missing?

Comment: It matters where the pump is. The pump will experience the downward force to counteract the rider's upward force. Usually the pump is near the end of the hose; floating in the water. Everything directly attached to the rider only accelerates the water downwards, thus accelerating the rider upwards. Only the pump (and technically the hose) accelerates the water upwards

Comment: Yes, as dmckee suggests the question [How does the 'water jet pack' work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8947/how-does-the-water-jet-pack-work) is an obvious duplicate.

Comment: @JohnRennie I dont think its an obvious duplicate. That Q just asks how a water jet pack works. My Q asks how 2 forces in 2 opposite directions producing 2 opposite-equal reactions can somehow produce a net thrust. However, David Cary's answer from the link was helpful.

Comment: I've added [an answer to the duplicate question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210243/1325) explaining exactly why the jetpack files.